# How to convert ":" colonized names from XML to XSD schema?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I want to generate POJOS using xjc from JAXB from a XSD schema. I am having trouble converting elements with names like "media:title" to schema.

```
<media:title>Sink or Swim - Trailer</media:title>
<media:credit role="Director" scheme="urn:ebu">Jon Bowermaster</media:credit>
<media:credit role="Writer" scheme="urn:ebu">Jon Bowermaster</media:credit>
<media:credit role="Editor" scheme="urn:ebu">Devin Pickering</media:credit>
<media:thumbnail type="landscape" url="http://snagfilms-a.akamaihd.net/bf/f6/41421f834ff49b86e36beae9f47e/sinkorswim-video.jpg"/>
<media:thumbnail type="thumbnail" url="http://snagfilms-a.akamaihd.net/11/50/68399aa743ffa9fa9f9a155ba1c1/sinkorswim-thumbnail.jpg"/>
<media:thumbnail type="widget" url="http://snagfilms-a.akamaihd.net/ce/f7/5a967d1042288b53fecdf100393a/sinkorswim-widget.jpg"/>
<media:thumbnail type="poster" url="http://snagfilms-a.akamaihd.net/30/40/0875f149490a853057bebf69dac0/sinkorswim-poster.jpg"/>
<media:content duration="117" height="323" type="text/html" url="http://embed.snagfilms.com/embed/player?filmId=00000158-b20c-d8f9-affd-b32ce8700000" width="500"/>
<media:keywords>
snagfilms,Trailers,Climate Change,Documentary,Inspiring,Maldives,Swimming,Trailers
</media:keywords>
<media:restriction relationship="allow" type="sharing"/>
<media:community>
  <media:starRating average="0" count="0"/>
  <media:statistics favorites="5" views="5"/>
  <media:tags>
  snagfilms,Trailers,Climate Change,Documentary,Inspiring,Maldives,Swimming,Trailers
  </media:tags>
</media:community>
<media:rights status="official"/>
<media:player height="323" url="http://embed.snagfilms.com/embed/player?filmId=00000158-b20c-d8f9-affd-b32ce8700000" width="500"/>
```

What will the above look like in XSD schema

Answer (score 2):

To ask *how to convert colonized names from XML to XSD* indicates a misunderstanding of XML namespaces.  Colonized names are a way to place an XML component into a namespace via a namespace prefix.  You don't want to *convert* XML to XSD; you want to write an XSD that *describes* the XML.

In your example markup, there should be

- a single root element
- a declaration of the `media` namespace prefix (eg: `xmlns:media="http://www.example.com/media"`)

Lacking these items, your markup isn't even XML because it doesn't meet the requirements for being *well-formed*.

After making these corrections, you can write an XSD that has a target namespace that matches the namespace of the root element of your XML.  You can import additional XSD to cover an additional namespaces used in your XML.  Only then will you be ready to generate Java classes via JAXB and xjc.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to the concept. This is the original response I am getting http://www.snagfilms.com/feeds/ so do you mean I need to use "targetNamespace=media" for those elements. Can you help me out with the syntax?

Comment: No, you need fundamental knowledge of XML namespaces, not just help with the syntax.  Read a basic introduction to the topic first.  You're clearly not ready to ask the right questions, let alone understand the answers, until you do that.